# Can't run two rows three column string array with C#

Tags: c#

My Code is here. But I get two errors.Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializers. Try using new expression instead.

```
using System;

public class twoDimArray
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   String[] city=new String[] { {"NewYork","Muscat","London"} ,{"Cairo","Beijing","CapeTown"}  };

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {for (int j=0; j<3; j++)

   {
      System.Console.Write(city[i][j]+"\t");
  }
      System.Console.Write("\n");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is error in this

Answer (score 4):

Change your declaration to

```
String[,] city = new String[,] { 
                     { "NewYork", "Muscat", "London" }, 
                     { "Cairo", "Beijing", "CapeTown" } };
```

And instead of hardcoding the upperbounds, this would be much better

```
for (int i = 0; i < city.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < city.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(city[i, j] + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String[,] city=new String[,] { {"NewYork","Muscat","London"} ,{"Cairo","Beijing","CapeTown"}  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] city=new String[] { "NewYork","Muscat","London","Cairo","Beijing","CapeTown"  };
```

instead of:

```
String[] city=new String[] { {"NewYork","Muscat","London"} ,{"Cairo","Beijing","CapeTown"}  };
```

Second one is wrong because you are initializing 2 other arrays in one array.

```
var city=new List<String[]> {new [] {"NewYork","Muscat","London"} , new []{"Cairo","Beijing","CapeTown"}};
```

This will create list of string arrays, or this code will create 2 dimensional array:

```
String[,] city=new String[,] { {"NewYork","Muscat","London"} ,{"Cairo","Beijing","CapeTown"}  };
```

Answer (score 1):

`String[] city=new String[]` is ONE dimentional array ....

`use String[,] city=new String[,]()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends on what you are trying to achieve. If it's 2-dimensional array, you should use:

```
String[,] city = new String[,]{ { "NewYork", "Muscat", "London" }, { "Cairo", "Beijing", "CapeTown" } };
```

and call, for example, it like this:

```
System.Console.Write(city[0, 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although using

```
   string[,] = new string...
```

can work fine, i wouldn't recommend it if you need to serialize it. I'd rather use list of list of strings.

```
 List<object> firstLevel = new List<object>();
 List<string> secondLevel = new List<string>("first", "second", "third");
 firstLevel.Add(secondLevel);
 secondLevel = ("first", "second", "third");
 firstLevel.Add(secondLevel);
```